# Reordenar barras no ggplot2 de acordo com uma das variáveis de preenchimento (fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá,

Tenho um gráfico que mostra a proporção de equipamentos disponíveis nas escolas de Pernambuco, e gostaria de ordena-lo dos equipamentos com maior presença (maior possui) para os com menor presença:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente o meu código está assim:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=equipamento ,y=perc, fill=situacao), arrange(situacao)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Percentual de creches que atendem aos parâmetros do CAQi") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Dada a disposição dos meus dados, não sei se é possível reordenar usando factor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: `dput(df)`, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Use a função fct_reorder do pacote forcats para isso.

```
df %>%
  mutate(equipamento, = fct_reorder(equipamento, perc)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=equipamento ,y=perc, fill=situacao), arrange(situacao)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Percentual de creches que atendem aos parâmetros do CAQi") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Guilherme, é quase isso. o `fct_reorder` reordenou pelo maior percentual, dessa forma a cozinha ficou em primeiro mas o restante ficou em ordem crescente de não possui (porque são os maiores percentuais), e o que eu gostaria é que ficasse em ordem decrescente de "possui" .

Answer (score 1):

Porque não utilizar o fct_reorder2? Com isso, você pode ordenar as duas variáveis de preferência.

```
df %>%
 mutate(equipamento = fct_reorder2(equipamento,situacao, perc)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=equipamento ,y=perc, fill=situacao), arrange(situacao)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Percentual de creches que atendem aos parâmetros do CAQi") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```